# how to get current ssl client X509 certificate in play framework 1.2.x

Tags: java, ssl, playframework, netty, playframework-1.x

At play! documentation here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration in the section **trustmanager** says that with `play.netty.clientAuth` you can request client certificate for the SSL handshake,

I want to get the client certificate for authentication against my own database in a play! 1.2.x controller, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The document you mentioned is all about making client - Play server connection secure, not about DB connection. If you want secure DB connection (don't know what DB you are using) - each DB has its own way of doing the same - check these links [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-connections.html).

Comment: I know how to authenticate a client against my database, what I want is to get the X509 Certificate the user has used to initiate SSL connection

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this, (or even it is the right thing to do) as client certificate is nothing but cert contains the public key you generated and shared (may be signed/shared via CA). You will have this cert anyway, why don't you use the same pair with DB ssl connection?

Comment: I don't understand your comment very well, but I need the certificate as user credential for access and authorization. I will search my database for serial of that certificate and according that I will give permissions

Comment: I still don't fathom your requirement completely. From what I undertand, you are trying to get details from client cert and use that details to authenticate DB connection? If so, please don't re-invent the wheel, esp autherization/authentication/security by your own. There are time tested, foolproof methodologies exists. Please re-use them. (Client - Server over ssl, get the client details(not anything from ssl cert) and server-db on another ssl) Also, please elaborate you requirement if you think I got you wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want the client certificate details to validate the user against my database, but in play framework server code I am unable to get any client certificate details and that's my question, I don't want to use any additional username password only the certificate